# NumPy: np.lexsort with fuzzy/tolerant comparisons

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, floating-point

I have a collection of `N` points in three dimensions.  These are stored as an `np.array` with a shape of `(N,3)`.  All of the points are distinct with the minimum distance between any two points being `~1e-5`.  I am looking for a means of obtaining an order in which to iterate over these points which is both independent of their current order in the `np.array` and robust to small perturbations of individual components.

The simplest means of satisfying the first requirement is with `np.lexsort` with

```
np.lexsort(my_array.T)
```

however this fails in the robustness department:

```
In [6]: my_array = np.array([[-0.5, 0, 2**0.5], [0.5, 0, 2**0.5 - 1e-15]])

In [7]: my_array[np.lexsort(my_array.T)]
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
       [-0.5       ,  0.        ,  1.41421356]])
```

where we can see that in this instance the ordering is extremely sensitive to perturbations.  I am therefore looking for a fuzzy variant of `np.lexsort` which will move onto the next axis if two values in one axis are within a tolerance of `epsilon`.  (Or any alternative mechanism which will permit me to obtain an ordering.)

As my application has several million of these collections, all of which need ordering, performance is something of a concern (which is why I have not blindly tried to roll my own tolerant np.lexsort without first seeing if there is a better way to do it).

Comment: I need the same thing for sorting complex numbers first by real part and then by imaginary part, but the real part sort should consider numbers equal if they're within some tolerance.  Did you ever find a solution?  What I was doing before was using lexsort to get them approximately sorted first, and then iterating through with a less optimal bubble-sort-like algorithm to group the values that are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

My eventual solution was:

```
def fuzzysort(arr, idx, dim=0, tol=1e-6):
    # Extract our dimension and argsort
    arrd = arr[dim]
    srtdidx = sorted(idx, key=arrd.__getitem__)

    i, ix = 0, srtdidx[0]
    for j, jx in enumerate(srtdidx[1:], start=1):
        if arrd[jx] - arrd[ix] >= tol:
            if j - i > 1:
                srtdidx[i:j] = fuzzysort(arr, srtdidx[i:j], dim + 1, tol)
            i, ix = j, jx

    if i != j:
        srtdidx[i:] = fuzzysort(arr, srtdidx[i:], dim + 1, tol)

    return srtdidx
```

I note that this is slightly over-engineered for the problem described above.  As with `np.lexsort` the array must be passed in transposed form.  The `idx` parameter permits one to control what indices are considered (allowing for elements to be crudely masked).  Otherwise `list(xrange(0, N))` will do.

Performance isn't great.  However, this is mostly a consequence of NumPy scalar types behaving badly.  Calling `tolist()` on the array beforehand improves the situation somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled in the same problem, only in 2D with a list of x, y coordinates that I needed to sort with a tolerance. I ended up writing this solution based on `numpy.lexsort`:

```
def tolerance_sort(array, tolerance):
    array_sorted = np.copy(array[np.lexsort((array[:, 0], array[:, 1]))])
    sort_range = [0]
    for i in range(array.shape[0] - 1):
        if array_sorted[i + 1, 1] - array_sorted[i, 1] <= tolerance:
            sort_range.append(i + 1)
            continue
        else:
            sub_arr = np.take(array_sorted, sort_range, axis=0)
            sub_arr_ord = np.copy(
                sub_arr[np.lexsort((sub_arr[:, 1], sub_arr[:, 0]))])
            array_sorted[slice(sort_range[0], sort_range[-1] +
                               1)] = sub_arr_ord
            sort_range = [i + 1]
    return array_sorted
```

which sorts this:

```
array([[ 11.  ,   4.  ],
       [  1.  ,   0.  ],
       [  7.  ,  10.  ],
       [  2.  ,   9.  ],
       [  9.  ,   9.  ],
       [  5.  ,   4.  ],
       [  1.  ,   2.  ],
       [  1.  ,   0.  ],
       [  0.  ,   0.1 ],
       [  2.  ,   0.06]])
```

into this (`tolerance = 0.1`):

```
array([[  0.  ,   0.1 ],
       [  1.  ,   0.  ],
       [  1.  ,   0.  ],
       [  2.  ,   0.06],
       [  1.  ,   2.  ],
       [  5.  ,   4.  ],
       [ 11.  ,   4.  ],
       [  2.  ,   9.  ],
       [  9.  ,   9.  ],
       [  7.  ,  10.  ]])
```

I didn't have time for generalization, so this only works in 2D and presently you have no control on the order of the sorting (first by the second column and then by the first).